# Programming Xbox: creating non-game applications for Xbox 360

Tags: process, service, controls, xbox

Our latest product is a gaming-center management software, currently taking good care of client PCs used by gaming center users. Since the number of gaming centers employing gaming consoles is rising in our country, the decision was made to add some console management capabilities to our product. These features would involve communicating to the server PC of the gaming-center through a LAN connection, and closing running games or resetting the console whenever user's credit is over.

Wherever I look on the Internet I find guides to creating games for the Xbox 360, but none seem to talk about creating service-like applications for this console.

Is Xbox 360 capable of running such applications? If it is, can I have access to and control over processes (i.e. games) running on the console?

If you know any resource providing more information on programming the Xbox 360 in this way, please do share.

Thanks.